# Is there any way to apply the Tailwindcss dark tag in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

I follow this :
https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/interoperability/#tailwind-css

and I use nextjs framework and tailwindcss is integrated in it. To make things easier, I tried adding the tailwind dark tag to a widget, but that doesn't work. I have configured the global dark toggle via MUI
theme.tsx

```
const roboto = Roboto({
  weight: ['300', '400', '500', '700', '900'],
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
});

export const useDarkMode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<'light' | 'dark'>('light');
  // const prefersDarkMode = useMediaQuery('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () => {
        setMode((prevMode) => (prevMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'));
      },
    }),
    [],
  );

  const theme = useMemo(
    () => createTheme({
      palette: {
        // mode: prefersDarkMode? 'dark' : 'light',
        mode,
      },
      typography: {
        fontFamily: roboto.style.fontFamily,
      },
    }),
    [mode],
  );
  
  return { theme, colorMode };

}

export const DarkModeContext = createContext({ toggleColorMode: () => {} });
```

Layout.tsx

```
<html lang="en">
      <body>
      <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
        <AppRouterCacheProvider options={{ key: 'css', enableCssLayer: true }}>
          <DarkModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
                  {children}
                </Box>
              </Box>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </DarkModeContext.Provider>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
      </StyledEngineProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I want using tailwind `dark:bg-slate-800` like this:

```
<CardHeader className="bg-slate-300 dark:bg-slate-800" title="Hello" />
```